# How to make ui-grid's corner rounded?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Listview has a data-inset property to make its corners rounded. However, I can't use listview because my list is a nested list and the frameworks default behavior is hide the nested list and show it once the its primary list is clicked. So, I chose to use a ui-grid view inside the primary listview row which looks like below:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
<li><h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Completeness</h1></li>
<li>
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<div>Secondary Title</div>
<div>Content.....</div>
<div>Blah Blah</div>
</div
</li>
<li>Footer</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the ui-grid's corners should be rounded. I tried to put data-inset="true" but didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the classes that jQuery Mobile adds to widgets, in this case you're looking for the `ui-corner-all` class which puts corners on all four corners, and then you will probably want the `box-shadow` that `ui-shadow` applies:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding: 5px;">
```

I added the padding because the grid element didn't have any by default. Also there are the `ui-corner-top` and `ui-corner-bottom` classes that only round the top/bottom of the element to which they are applied.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VXrxv/

If instead you want to round the `li` element that is the parent of the `ui-grid` element you can add `margin` to them:

```
<li class="ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="margin: 5px;">
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VXrxv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with css property `border-radius`. For example, try `border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em;`

Comment: thanks, it will create radius but the grid's radius looks different from the rest of the boxes on the page. Isn't there method or property on the framework itself that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the Bootstrap the rounding is effected;

This seems to be the quickest solution for me;

Wrap mist widgets with the following div

```
<div class="k-block" style="padding:0px">
```